# Passing multiple strings as single function parameter

Tags: function, powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to send email to multiple recipients in PowerShell.

I know about the PowerShell 1.0 way but I do not want to use it.

My email function looks like this

```
function Send-Mail() {

    Param ( 
            # email attributes    
            [string]$smtpServer,
            [string]$from,
            [string[]]$to,
            [string]$subject,
            [string]$body
    )

    Send-MailMessage -To $to -Subject $subject -BodyAsHtml $body -SmtpServer $smtpServer -From $from 
}
```

I can achieve what I want doing this:

```
$smtpServer = "email.server.local"
$from = "sender@email.com"
$subject = "Subject"
$body = "Test"

Send-Mail $smtpServer $from ("user1@email.com", "user2@email.com") $subject $body
```

..but if I put

```
$to = "user1@email.com", "user2@email.com"
Send-Mail $smtpServer $from $to $subject $body
```

Mail only goes to the second recipient

If I set `$to` locally in the function, this also works correctly, so the problem is passing the parameter to the function.

Comment: What does _I know about the PowerShell 1.0 way but I do not want to use it._ mean?

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you using? `Get-Host`. I don't see and issue here with your second example and this is working for me.

Comment: @Paul That does not work. $to wants a string array that it will unroll. When using the unary operator will convert it to a space delimited string.... unless you change the function parameter type as well.

Comment: Are you certain that the second recipient did not get the mail? I think you need to do some message tracking to be sure junk, spam, rules? If one user got it that means the string array is being parsed properly. Again, this works for me an I am on v4. Is there more to your function... all it is doing is calling the one cmdlet. You might as well use splatting as it is less redundant that way.

Comment: Yes definitely...Both accounts are under my control and like I said, I can see mail arrive in both mailboxes in the first example, but not in the second.

Comment: Did you have `$to` strongly cast in your current session at some point? `$to.GetType().fullname`

Comment: That returns as a System.String

Comment: AHA..... that would be an issue then. It should be a `system.object[]` or `system.string[]`. Save your code and reopen ISE / PS with a new session. Does it work then? If you strongly cast the variable you would not be able to change it later without first removing it. `Remove-Variable to`

Comment: Your comment before this prompted me to do a `rm variable:to` . Have just re-run the code and it's working. Thanks a lot as this has bugged me out since last night. Phew! Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sent it like this and it worked like a charm. PS v4, Windows Server 2012

```
Send-MailMessage -To "firstemail@domain.com", "secondemail@domain2.com" -Body "TEST" -From "test@domain.com" -Subject "TEST" -SmtpServer smarthost.domain.com
```

for your function purposes, I would submit the emails as an array. This also worked for me.

```
$array = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$array += "email1@domain1.com"
$array += "email2@domain2.com"
Send-MailMessage -To $array -Body "TEST" -From "test@domain.com" -Subject "TEST" -SmtpServer smarthost.domain.com
```

...and ultimately, this worked for me just fine using your function.

```
function Send-Mail() {
    Param ( 
        # email attributes    
        [string]$smtpServer,
        [string]$from,
        [string[]]$to,
        [string]$subject,
        [string]$body
    )
    Send-MailMessage -To $to -Subject $subject -BodyAsHtml $body -SmtpServer $smtpServer -From $from 
}
$array  = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$array += "email1@domain1.com"
$array += "email2@domain2.com"
Send-Mail -smtpServer "smarthost.domain.com" `
          -from       "test@domain.com"      `
          -to         $array                 `
          -subject    "Test"                 `
          -body       "TEST"
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you have listed here should have worked just fine. PowerShell is rather forgiving when it comes to typing and it will make the best selection for you. However you are able to cast yourself as `[string]` for example which I suspect your did at some point in your session before you hosted. Consider the following examples

```
PS C:\Users\matt> $to = "user1@email.com", "user2@email.com"

PS C:\Users\matt> $to.GetType().Fullname
System.Object[]

PS C:\Users\matt> [string]$to = "user1@email.com"

PS C:\Users\matt> $to.GetType().Fullname
System.String

PS C:\Users\matt> $to = "user1@email.com", "user2@email.com"

PS C:\Users\matt> $to.GetType().Fullname
System.String
```

Note that in the last set you might have expected `System.Object[]` but since it was strongly cast in an earlier line that it *remains that type* until it is removed.

You can also see this when examining the variable

```
PS C:\Users\mcameron> Get-Variable to | fl

Name        : to
.... output truncated ...
Attributes  : {System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTypeConverterAttribute}
```

Key point here is the Attribute `System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTypeConverterAttribute` which showed up after the strong cast. During a session or during code execution you can simple remove the variable with `Remove-Variable to` which would let you start over.

Comment: Thanks for the above explanation. It would have been more useful if you put the console output under your inputs in the initial section so it was easier to follow EDIT:  Just seen that you did do that but the highlighting confuses things (at least to me). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`$to = @("user1@email.com", "user2@email.com")` will set `$to` to be an array

Comment: That still doesn't work unfortunately. I should have mentioned that I had tried that.

Comment: What version of powershell? Is Set-StrictMode active? Any other attempts you have tried?

Comment: Version is PowerShell 4.0 and Strict Mode is active

Comment: In this context `("user1@email.com", "user2@email.com").GetType().fullname` is the same as `@("user1@email.com", "user2@email.com").GetType().fullname`. PowerShell is smart enough to figure this one out.